# Set Form dimensions related to panel dimensions

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm using C# and I have a WinForms application.

I have a main form which contains some buttons, lets say button A and B.
I have another form,FormB which have 2 panels with different dimensions.

What I'm trying to do is when the user clicks on button A is to show FormB with
the dimensions of the first panel and present the first panel.
And when the user clicks on button B is to show formB with the second panel dimensions 
and present the second panel.

I know How to present those panel in each case but the form size doesn't change as I expected.

I tried to use the **Dock** property and set it to fill.. but nothing happens.

```
    private void FormB_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panel1.Location = panel2.Location = new Point();
        timer1.Start();

        if (!first)
        {
            panel1.Visible = false;
            panel2.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            panel1.Visible = true;
            panel2.Visible = false;
        }
        this.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `panel1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill` or `panel2.Dock = DockStyle.Fill`, not `this.Dock = DockStyle.Fill` because you want to set the Dock property of the `Panel` not the `Form`.

```
private void FormB_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panel1.Location = panel2.Location = new Point();
        timer1.Start();

        if (!first)
        {
            panel1.Visible = false;
            panel2.Visible = true;
            panel2.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        }
        else
        {
            panel1.Visible = true;
            panel2.Visible = false;
            panel1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        }
    }
```

**EDIT** But previous code will change the size of the panels according to the size of the form. Since you want to set the size of the form to be the size of the panel(s), then you should set the `Size` property of the `Form` like this:

```
    private void FormB_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panel1.Location = panel2.Location = new Point();
        timer1.Start();

        if (!first)
        {
            panel1.Visible = false;
            panel2.Visible = true;
            this.Size = new Size(panel2.Size.Width + 16, panel2.Size.Height + 38);
        }
        else
        {
            panel1.Visible = true;
            panel2.Visible = false;
            this.Size = new Size(panel1.Size.Width + 16, panel1.Size.Height + 38);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I also tried to use the Size property before I post my question but 
it's hiding the bottom of the panels.. I think I need to increase the panels height.. for some reason it doesn't give me the right height of the panels.. In the design view I see the panels correctly as the need to be.. but in runtime it's hiding some section from the bottom

Comment: No, just to add more to height and width because of borders, I'll edit

Comment: I've edited the answer. This should be roughly the sizes of the borders and the form's caption.

Comment: thanks! there is a reason for those numbers or it's hard coded?

Comment: Hm, hardcoded for the Form but I'm not sure if they can be changed, maybe if someone changes default settings in windows. I saw that through debugger.

Comment: Ok! It works fine.. thanks! I'll also try to get this on runtime.. 
but thanks!